# Is is possible to do this with only one sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want have an insert query, but before inserting I check whether the username and email are used by someone else. If used, I want to cancel insert query and echo a message to say whether username or email is in use.

Here my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT 1 FROM user WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."'";
if(!$result = mysql_query($sql))
    die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    die('This username is already exists');
$sql = "SELECT 2 FROM user WHERE email='".$_POST['email']."'";
if(!$result = mysql_query($sql))
    die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    die('This email address is already exists');
$sql = "insert into user (username,email,password,tel,type) values ('".$_POST['username']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['password']."','".$_POST['telnumber']."','member')";
if(!mysql_query($sql))
    die(mysql_error());
```

**I want these three sql statements in one. It can be either using cases or something else that you suggest. So,**
Is it possible to zip this code into one sql query?

As a result what I need is

```
sql = "sql_query"
if(!$result = mysql_query($sql))
    die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
if($row['result']==1)
    die('This username is already exists');
else if($row['result']==2)
    die('This email is already exists');
}
die('you have succesfully registered');
```

thanks for any advice.

Comment: If you can explain what you want to achieve and what you are doing in plain language, non-php folks would also be able to help and would be easy for php-folks to understand

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables?](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: As an aside, you probably want to bind your parameters (or at least escape them) before passing them to MySQL, unless you're overly fond of SQL injection attacks

Comment: I added some explanation about what I am doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I suggest you follow @cularis' answer, you may be interested in the following alternative:

1. Give `email` and `username` the `UNIQUE` constraint, by creating a unique index for both of these.
2. run your `INSERT` query, and if this fails... (due to duplicate keys)
3. run the suggested combined `SELECT`, to determine which field existed (username or email)

Comment: it is the best solution up to now

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the first two queries like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."' OR email='".$_POST['email']."'";
```

Have look at [mysql_real_escape string](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to sanatize your input.

Comment: But with this query I cannot notice whether username or email is used.

Comment: Sure, you check what is returned by the query and find out if it is the email, username or both.

Comment: @exculuber: Can't you check the resulting rows? if username != username_arg then email == email_arg

Comment: it is not efficient and it is useless

Comment: Its way more efficient than sending 1 query per input parameter.

Comment: which one is better using 2 sql queries for 2 input parameters or using 3 sql queries for 2 input parameters?

Comment: @exculuber: I'm confused here, I think. Why would you need additional queries? this gives you a single query for both, you don't need to query the server again, just process the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't care about a more specific error case you could probably just do the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."' OR email='".$_POST['email']."'";
if(!$result = mysql_query($sql))
    die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    die('The username or email address is already being used');
$sql = "insert into user (username,email,password,tel,type) values ('".$_POST['username']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['password']."','".$_POST['telnumber']."','member')";
if(!mysql_query($sql))
    die(mysql_error());
```

This isn't the best of designs if you're looking for, as I said, specific error cases. So if you are okay with just telling the person there is an error that one or both are in use then that should work.

I am not sure as I am very rusty in PHP/MySQL but I assume that if such cases of both exist then multiple rows may be returned and I forget exactly how mysql_fetch_array works but I assume it's an array of all results valid for the query so you should be set. As long as the array exists, you know there was a hit in the db.

Comment: can you look at my question again?